# Why can duplicates be marked as duplicates?

Tags: bug, feature-request

[Should I use whose or which's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65362/should-i-use-whose-or-whichs) has been closed as a duplicate of several other closed duplicates ([Usage of “whose” not referring to a person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/usage-of-whose-not-referring-to-a-person), [Possessive "that's"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25300/possessive-thats), [Possessive connecting word for inanimate object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/possessive-connecting-word-for-inanimate-object)). I cannot cite other specific examples of this happening, but I remember it as more than rare, albeit less than common. In any case, this is unhelpful to future users who stumble across such questions—they should be directly linked to a non-closed question.

Possible ideas for fixing:

- Do not allow duplicate questions to be marked as the anti-duplicate. (By anti-duplicate, I mean the question that the duplicate is a duplicate of, if that makes sense. I don't know what to call it.) If Question B is marked as a duplicate of Question A, SE should not allow B to be linked as a duplicate of Question C.
- If a duplicate question is proposed as the anti-duplicate, put *that* question's anti-duplicate as the anti-duplicate. If Question B is marked as a duplicate of Question A, and then Question C is marked as a duplicate of B, SE should automagically link to A instead of B.

<sub>My apologies if I haven't asked a good question or if I haven't tagged this right. If I haven't, please feel free to correct me.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious to me there's anything wrong with the current system.

Note that I don't mind questions being closed even if they're not *exact* duplicates - if the original can easily be enhanced with minor edits and/or a new answer to address both questions, that's what I'd rather see.

Some (but not all) of the "possible duplicates" in OP's link have been closed themselves. I haven't checked them out in detail, but it's possible some of those that *haven't* been closed could be - either immediately, or following some minor changes to one of the other questions/answers.

We get a lot of questions covering essentially the same ground, but sometimes it takes a really good question/answer combination to highlight exactly *why* they're "the same thing".

Comment: My beef is that the closed duplicates are marked as possible duplicates; is this what you refer to as well? (I just reread my question and don't feel I was clear as I could have been.)

Comment: @zpletan: Even with that comment, I'm not 100% sure what your problem is. The *first* "possible duplicate" remains open, and is a true duplicate (though it only has a "correct, but not perfect" answer, imho). RegDwight presumably went to some trouble to round up the others. I can't see the additional links being problematic for anyone seeking answers - they'd obviously follow the first link first. The rest of us should perhaps check out the other links and see if there's anything we can do to tidy things up a bit. We can't expect RegDwight to do all the work!

Comment: OK—I can certainly appreciate the argument that a closed question might itself have a great answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Of course he can, he's a [glutton for punishment](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/64633/19125)!

Answer (score 1):

> "Should I use whose or which's?" has been closed as a duplicate of several other closed duplicates

Actually, a question is closed as duplicate of a single question. [The text originally inserted](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/ac282366-2d4c-4779-89e2-c1dbc27d1479/view-source) in the question to report the duplicated question is the following one:

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other ways of saying whichs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/other-ways-of-saying-whichs)

The system automatically insert other links, if the users who voted to close the question, selected more than one question (which means a user selected a questions that was not selected by the other users). This is not what happened in this case, as the [other links were manually inserted by RegDwight](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/ac1f4ea1-d55d-47bc-896e-0bcda8dedd02/view-source).

As per allowing to close a question as duplicate of a question that is already closed as duplicate, there is at least a case where this is valid.

- A user asks a question (B) that duplicates an existing question (A).
- The question gets closed.
- The user asks a new question (C), using the same text used for B.

In this case, it makes more sense to close C as duplicate of B, as in this case the questions are exact duplicates of each other.

I don't see also any reason for not allowing to close a question as duplicate of another question that is already closed as duplicate. Users should be free to choose the question that is more close to be a duplicate, even in the case the question is already a duplicate.

Comment: "Users should be free to choose the question that is a more significative [significant?] duplicate, even in the case the question is already a duplicate." This is another good argument. Thanks!